# How to combine tibble in R

Tags: r

I am trying to combine 3 tibbles into one large tibble. The 3 tibbles have varying lengths, but the variables in each tibble are the same

[image: I am trying to combine 3 tibbles into one large tibble. The 3 tibbles have varying lengths, but the variables in each tibble are the same]

Comment: Try `rbind(data1, data2, data3)`. Or just `filter(Clean_data, country %in% c("United States of America", "Mexico", "Canada"))`.

Comment: The selections are all from the same source `data.frame` - just select once - `filter(Clean_data, country %in% c("United States of America","Mexico","Canada"))`

Comment: Thank you for the input. I will try it out now :)

Comment: Please don't upload code or data as images for [these reasons](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557).

Answer (score 3):

`dplyr`'s `bind_rows()` is useful for combining data frames wherein the columns are all identical. (`bind_cols()` being the equivalent for combining data frames in order to add columns to existing rows).

```
new_data <- bind_rows(data1, data2, data3)
```

Answer (score 2):

In **Base R**,

I would rather use vectorization instead of creating three different tibbles per country by this:

```
data_filtered <- Clean_data[Clean_data$country %in% c("United States of America", "Mexico", "Canada"),]
```

If you just want to combine the three tibbles `rbind()` works well if the columns are identical.

```
data_filtered <- rbind(data1, data2, data3)
```